# How to replace strings in column with ordered numbers?

Tags: google-bigquery

I have the following table:

```
CityNamesZip5Plus4

===========================

Zip5    Plus4   CityName
===========================
36067   1500    Prattville
36067   1501    Prattville
36067   1502    Prattville

48085   3614    Troy
48085   3629    Troy
48085   3640    Troy
48085   3641    Troy
```

Need to replace CityName with numbers beginning from 1

so the table to look like this:

CityNameNumberZip5Plus4

```
===========================

Zip5    Plus4   CityNameNumber
===========================
36067   1500    1
36067   1501    1
36067   1502    1

48085   3614    2
48085   3629    2
48085   3640    2
48085   3641    2
```

The CityName -> CityNameNumber correspondency should be in separate table : CityNamesNumbers

Th question is how to generate CityNamesNumbers table and use it
to generate  CityNameNumberZip5Plus4?

Comment: SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY CityName) AS RowNumber
        ,count(*) AS CityNameNumber 
    from table 
    group by CityName

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL

> how to generate CityNamesNumbers table ...

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.CityNamesNumbers` AS
SELECT CityName, ROW_NUMBER() OVER() CityNameNumber 
FROM `project.dataset.CityNamesZip5Plus4`
GROUP BY CityName
```

> ... and use it to generate CityNameNumberZip5Plus4?

```
#standardSQL
CREATE OR REPLACE TABLE `project.dataset.CityNameNumberZip5Plus4` AS
SELECT x.* EXCEPT(CityName), CityNameNumber
FROM `project.dataset.CityNamesZip5Plus4` x
JOIN `project.dataset.CityNamesNumbers` y
USING(CityName)
```